# Ruby on Rails, jquery doesn't assign value to model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a basic form in my Ruby on Rails application. One of the fields is calculated according to others. If validation fails, and `new` action is rendered, calculated value is evaporated.

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord

end
```

This is my controller:

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @model = Model.new(secure_params)

        if @model.save
          redirect_to @model
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def secure_params
       params.require(:model).permit(:count,:unitPrice,:totalPrice);                            
    end

end
```

This is new.html.erb form:

```
<%= form_with model: @model, local: true do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :count %><br>
      <%= form.number_field :count, id:'count' %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :unitPrice %><br>
      <%= form.number_field :unitPrice, id:'unitPrice' %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :totalPrice %><br>
      <%= form.number_field :totalPrice, id:'totalPrice' %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<script>

  function calculateTotalPrice(){

     var count=$("#count").val();
     var unitPrice=$("#unitPrice").val();

     if(unitPrice && count ){
        var totalPrice=parseFloat(unitPrice*count).toFixed(2);
        $("#totalPrice").val(totalPrice); 
     }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#count").bind('keyup mouseup',calculateTotalPrice);
      $("#unitPrice").bind('keyup mouseup',calculateTotalPrice);

  });

</script>
```

When I submit the form, if validation is ok then there is no problem. But if model has errors, totalPrice value is removed from model. I think value inserted to totalPrice field is not injected to the Ruby model.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Given that the unitPrice and count are strings, does this part seem odd to you?  `parseFloat(unitPrice*count)`

Comment: I have removed parseFloat(), nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery looks fine.

It could be blocked because number inputs only accept integer values by default. Setting parameter step to 'any' will allow for decimal values. Try:

`<%= form.number_field :totalPrice, id:'totalPrice', step: :any %>`

Also, double check that the totalPrice field is not of type integer in Model, but rather float or decimal.